# Do form exports include forms related to closed cases?

Tags: commcare

When I do a form export, does it also include form submissions related to closed cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the form submission doesn't have any errors associated with it, it will by default be included in a form export, even if the case that it opened/is related to is closed.